# fake a filename for filetype detection when reading from stdin

Tags: filetype

When reading from stdin with something like `fancy-command | vim -R -`, vim does not detect the `filetype` (i.e. `set filetype` prints `filetype=`). When I know the right vim filetype, I can provide it from the command line (or from within vim) with `fancy-command | vim -R +'set ft=cpp' -`.

Now, that pipe might be in a shell script e.g. in conjunction with `git show <commit hash>:<path>`, such that I don't want to hardcode `cpp` as filetype. I have thought about just taking the end of `<path>` and provide it to `ft=`, but I expect this to fail (`CMakeLists.txt` are not identified by their suffix).

So what I'd like to do is run vim's `filetype detect` but with a pretended filename when vim is actually reading from stdin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

cat $file | vim -c "doautocmd BufRead $file" -
```

This will run the autocommands that would normally run, when you would open a file with the given name. This includes filetype detection.

To my surprise, this also works when the file name contains a space.

The name is only used to run the autocommands, the name of the loaded buffer is not changed (it still is `[No Name]`).